# I want someone to solve my query, i want 2 rows of 3 images

Tags: html, css, position

someone look at this code and rearrange it if its too messy and back and forth.. i m new to learning css so need your help.. 
i want 2 rows of 3 images below  "Section" class 
how to do it,, i tried float,position its not working, tell me where i am doing wrong..

i am using image with dimension :  1920*1080

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
html{
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    color:white;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
header{
    background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(8, 141, 8, 0.719),grey),url("key.jpg");
    height: 100vh;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position: center;
    position: relative;
}
h1{
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    font-family: 'Cinzel Decorative', cursive;
}
.text-box{
    position: absolute;
    left: 30%;
    top: 35%;
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
}
.btn1 ,.btn2 ,.btn3 {
    padding: 8px 20px;
    background-color: oldlace;
    margin-right: 60px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: grey;
    font-weight: 600;
    border-radius: 200px;
   }
.btn1:hover ,.btn2:hover ,.btn3:hover,
.btn1:active ,.btn2:active ,.btn3:active{
    background-color: rgba(136, 209, 77, 0.733);
    transition: 0.3s;
    border: steelblue 2px solid;
    color: #fff;
}
.logo{
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
}
.main-nav{
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
}

.main-nav li{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.main-nav li a{
    color:white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.main-nav li a:hover,
.main-nav li a:active{
    font-weight: 700;
}
.row{
    color: rgb(80, 77, 77);
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    
}

h2{
    color: rgb(80, 77, 77);
    font-weight: 900;
text-align: center;
padding-bottom: 2%;
}
.section {
 clear: both;
 padding: 80px 0px;
 margin: 0px;
}
.p1{
    padding: 0% 13%;
}
.row1{
    padding-top: 2%;
    left:18%; 
}
.row1 p{
    font-size: 90%;
    line-height: 30px;
}
.ion-social-html5,
.ion-social-javascript,
.ion-social-css3{
    font-size: 46px;
}
.ion-social-html5{
    color: orange;
}
.ion-social-javascript{
    color:rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.911);
}
.ion-social-css3{
    color:rgb(45, 45, 190);
}
h3{
    padding-bottom: 3%;
}
.html{
    padding-right: 5%;
}
.js{
    padding-left: 3%;
}
.photo-showcase{
   width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}

.fig img{
    max-width: 30%;
    max-height: 100vh;
    float: left;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Front End</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Monoton" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cinzel+Decorative:700|Monoton" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Black+Ops+One|Lato|Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="p2.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="032 grid.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="ionicons.css" />
    
    
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <div class="Nav">
                <img src="logo1.jpg" alt="logo" class="logo">
                <ul class="main-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">news</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
                </ul>
         </div>
                </nav>
        <div class="text-box"> 
            <h1>
            Front End Dev. <br>
            Where it all begins.
            </h1>
    <a class="btn1" href="#">Html</a>
        <a class="btn2" href="#">css</a>
        <a class="btn3" href="#">javascript</a>
    </div>
        </header>



        <section class="section">
            <div class="row">
                <h2>Front end Dev</h2>
                <p class="p1">
                        Front-end web development is the practice of producing HTML, CSS and usually JavaScript for a website or
                         Web Application so that a user can see and interact with them directly
                </p>
            </div>

            <div class="row row1">
                <div class="col span-1-of-4 html">
               
                    <h3>HTML <i class="ion-social-html5"></i></h3> 
                    <p>
                    Hypertext Markup Language is the standard markup language for creating web pages and web applications. 
                    With Cascading Style Sheets and JavaScript, it forms a triad of cornerstone technologies for the World Wide Web
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col span-1-of-4 css">
                        <h3>CSS <i class="ion-social-css3"></i> </h3>
                        <p>
                        Cascading Style Sheets is a style sheet language used for describing the presentation of a document written in a markup language.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col span-1-of-4 js">
                            <h3>JAVASCRIPT <i class="ion-social-javascript"></i></h3>
                            <p>
                            JavaScript, often abbreviated as JS, is a high-level, interpreted programming language.
                            It is a language which is also characterized as dynamic, weakly typed, prototype-based and multi-paradigm.
                            </p>
                            
                        </div>
            </div>
            </section>
            <section class="Photo-showcase">
                <ul class="one">
                <li>
                    <figure class="fig"><img src="key.jpg"> </figure>
                </li>
                <li>
                        <figure class="fig"><img src="key.jpg"> </figure>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                            <figure class="fig"><img src="key.jpg"> </figure>
                        </li>
                    </ul> 
                    <ul class="one">
                            <li>
                                <figure class="fig"><img src="key.jpg"> </figure>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                    <figure class="fig"><img src="key.jpg"> </figure>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                        <figure class="fig"><img src="key.jpg"> </figure>
                                    </li>
                                </ul> 
                    
                       </section>
    
</body>
</html>
```

i dont know weather the problem is very simple or big i m just facing problem with these image positions..[this is the my current situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Bp4n.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: flex;`.

Add this in your `css`.

```
.Photo-showcase ul {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
```

**Remove**

```
.fig img {
    max-width: 30%;
    max-height: 100vh;
    float: left;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Also add this

```
.fig img { 
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

**Here the working code**

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
html{
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    color:white;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
header{
    background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(8, 141, 8, 0.719),grey),url("key.jpg");
    height: 100vh;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position: center;
    position: relative;
}
h1{
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    font-family: 'Cinzel Decorative', cursive;
}
.text-box{
    position: absolute;
    left: 30%;
    top: 35%;
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
}
.btn1 ,.btn2 ,.btn3 {
    padding: 8px 20px;
    background-color: oldlace;
    margin-right: 60px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: grey;
    font-weight: 600;
    border-radius: 200px;
   }
.btn1:hover ,.btn2:hover ,.btn3:hover,
.btn1:active ,.btn2:active ,.btn3:active{
    background-color: rgba(136, 209, 77, 0.733);
    transition: 0.3s;
    border: steelblue 2px solid;
    color: #fff;
}
.logo{
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
}
.main-nav{
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
}

.main-nav li{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.main-nav li a{
    color:white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.main-nav li a:hover,
.main-nav li a:active{
    font-weight: 700;
}
.row{
    color: rgb(80, 77, 77);
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    
}

h2{
    color: rgb(80, 77, 77);
    font-weight: 900;
text-align: center;
padding-bottom: 2%;
}
.section {
 clear: both;
 padding: 80px 0px;
 margin: 0px;
}
.p1{
    padding: 0% 13%;
}
.row1{
    padding-top: 2%;
    left:18%; 
}
.row1 p{
    font-size: 90%;
    line-height: 30px;
}
.ion-social-html5,
.ion-social-javascript,
.ion-social-css3{
    font-size: 46px;
}
.ion-social-html5{
    color: orange;
}
.ion-social-javascript{
    color:rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.911);
}
.ion-social-css3{
    color:rgb(45, 45, 190);
}
h3{
    padding-bottom: 3%;
}
.html{
    padding-right: 5%;
}
.js{
    padding-left: 3%;
}
.photo-showcase{
   width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}
.Photo-showcase ul {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin: 10px 0;
}

.fig img {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Monoton" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cinzel+Decorative:700|Monoton" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Black+Ops+One|Lato|Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <title>Front End</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
    <nav>
        <div class="Nav"> <img src="logo1.jpg" alt="logo" class="logo">
            <ul class="main-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">news</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="text-box">
        <h1> Front End Dev. <br>
            Where it all begins. </h1>
        <a class="btn1" href="#">Html</a> <a class="btn2" href="#">css</a> <a class="btn3" href="#">javascript</a> </div>
</header>
<section class="section">
    <div class="row">
        <h2>Front end Dev</h2>
        <p class="p1"> Front-end web development is the practice of producing HTML, CSS and usually JavaScript for a website or
            Web Application so that a user can see and interact with them directly </p>
    </div>
    <div class="row row1">
        <div class="col span-1-of-4 html">
            <h3>HTML <i class="ion-social-html5"></i></h3>
            <p> Hypertext Markup Language is the standard markup language for creating web pages and web applications. 
                With Cascading Style Sheets and JavaScript, it forms a triad of cornerstone technologies for the World Wide Web </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col span-1-of-4 css">
            <h3>CSS <i class="ion-social-css3"></i> </h3>
            <p> Cascading Style Sheets is a style sheet language used for describing the presentation of a document written in a markup language. </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col span-1-of-4 js">
            <h3>JAVASCRIPT <i class="ion-social-javascript"></i></h3>
            <p> JavaScript, often abbreviated as JS, is a high-level, interpreted programming language.
                It is a language which is also characterized as dynamic, weakly typed, prototype-based and multi-paradigm. </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="Photo-showcase">
    <ul class="one">
        <li>
            <figure class="fig"><img src="//s3.buysellads.com/1250418/293805-1444204566.png"> </figure>
        </li>
        <li>
            <figure class="fig"><img src="//s3.buysellads.com/1250418/293805-1444204566.png"> </figure>
        </li>
        <li>
            <figure class="fig"><img src="//s3.buysellads.com/1250418/293805-1444204566.png"> </figure>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="one">
        <li>
            <figure class="fig"><img src="//s3.buysellads.com/1250418/293805-1444204566.png"> </figure>
        </li>
        <li>
            <figure class="fig"><img src="//s3.buysellads.com/1250418/293805-1444204566.png"> </figure>
        </li>
        <li>
            <figure class="fig"><img src="//s3.buysellads.com/1250418/293805-1444204566.png"> </figure>
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank u for ur answer but still i m getting all 6 images one below the other and single image taking full width.. i took ur code and still the same

Comment: @DeadlyDev Did you Check my `work`.  Did you add `display: flex;` to your `.Photo-showcase ul` selector .

I update my answer please check now ...

Comment: ya bro i added flex property as u mentioned still the not working..  does large images causing problem?

Comment: Did you use `.fig img {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}` this . I added this in my work .
If you add this will , then problem is not `larg image`. @DeadlyDev

Comment: i tried it too.. still not working do u think learning bootstrap will make this all layout much easier? i having very hard time using pure css

Comment: @DeadlyDev, Can you `update` your question width `current work`.